# c# problem that doesnt let you input in a while loop

Tags: c#

```
class part2
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter Y / N");
        char ch = (char)Console.Read();
        while (ch == 'Y')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter Length, Width and Height");
            double len = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double wid = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double hei = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("enter N / Y");
            ch = (char)Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

hey, can anyone help me in this.
apparently i cant input in a while loop.
this is the error code,

```
enter Y / N
Y
enter Length, Width and Height

Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Double.Parse(String s)
   at part2.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\avi16\Desktop\Coding\files\c#\Targil2\Targil2\Program.cs:line 12
```

Comment: look at your exception. it has ***nothing*** to do with the loop. it has to do with your input (which you should _share_ with us) not being parsable into a double. (also important to answer this question: what _locale_ are you using in your program?)

Comment: the input is in the code ```double len = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());```

Comment: Your problem is that _"Input string was not in a correct format."_ What did you input? It evidently cannot be parsed into a `double`.

Comment: i didnt entered anything it just poped up

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is because you did a `Console.Read()` to capture the 'Y', but that didn't consume the residual carriage-return/linefeed character pair left over when you typed Y and pressed Return. (Your input was actually "Y" - the Console.Read() gave you the Y, leaving the  in the buffer)

This then means the next time you call Console.ReadLine() it instantly returns a blank string (because it immediately finds CRLF in the buffer left over from before), which cannot be parsed to a double..

Use `Console.ReadLine()` to capture your Y into a string variable instead of a char, and compare it to the string "Y", not the char 'Y'

```
    string ch = Console.ReadLine();
    while (ch == "Y")
```

You say you have to use a char, you could do this:

```
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    char ch = s[0]; //it takes the first char of the string
    while(ch == 'Y')
```

Note that it will cause a crash if the user enters nothing (doesn't type Y, just presses return). To protect against this you'll need to check that the `string s` has a `.Length` of `>1`

---

Another trick could be to use Read() to get your character but then put in a call to a ReadLine() just to consume the other stuff in the buffer:

```
char ch = (char)Console.Read();
Console.ReadLine(); //consume residual junk
while(...)
```

Comment: the program is now working, thanks, but one of the conditions in the example is to use char variable

Comment: OK, you can still use ReadLine but pull the first char off the input string - I'll make an edit

Comment: You can add `Console.ReadLine();` as the first line in the `while` loop. `double.TryParse()` is kind of required (or *old style* validation).

Comment: @Jimi thanks - i think we had coincidental thoughts

Comment: All right. But, `Console.ReadLine();` needs to be the first line **in the loop** (outside it's not needed), otherwise, the next confirmation, you're back at square one :) (since the OP really really wants to get a char there. So. I'd also change `while (char.ToUpper(ch).Equals('Y'))`)

Comment: Hah, well.. I can't do *all* their homework for them .. I was leaving that "end of loop repeat of the earlier bug" as an exercise for the reader but you should leave that comment as a pointer... If I were to romp through and head off *every* potential problem there might not be a lot left of the original code :)

Comment: That's quite probably true :)